# Sublime Text: run code in a new file without saving to disk and the default language setting for a new file

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am using Sublime Text Editor for Python development. If I create a new file by Ctrl + N, the default language setting for this file is Plain Text, so how to change the default language setting for the new file to be Python ?

Another question :If I write some code in the new file and have not save it to disk, it is impossible to run it and get the running result, is there a solution to remove this restriction so that we can run code in the new file without saving it to disk first?

Comment: https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType for the first one

Answer (score 3):

There are several packages available for setting the default syntax for new files. One, as mentioned in the comments, is [`Default File Type`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Default%20File%20Type), but I actually prefer [`ApplySyntax`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax). It automagically detects what the syntax of a file *should* be, based on a bunch of (user-configurable, of course) rules, and also sets the default syntax for new files.

The only way to run unsaved code in Sublime is to install the excellent [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) plugin. Among many other features, you can highlight and transfer code to a running REPL, or just enter the code directly in the REPL.

Comment: I installed SublimeREPL, how to run unsaved code 
?

Comment: Open a REPL, then switch to your code, select it, and click **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL -> Selection`**

Comment: I tried this, I am getting the error Cannot find REPL for 'python' ; I am testing some python blocks of code, and I dont want to save the file everytime. I have changed the file type to python in the file type selector at the bottom right of the screen

Answer (score 1):

**The second question about running without saving to hard disk:**

1-press ctrl + shift + p

2- write install package and install it

3- write "auto save" and install it

4- go to preferences> package settings> Auto-save> Settings Default and copy all the code

5- go to preferences> package settings> Auto-save> Settings user and past it and change the first code from:
"auto_save_on_modified": false,
to
"auto_save_on_modified": true,

good luck